# Setting a property of Object.prototype with assignment versus with defineProperty in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written a function in Javascript that removes the values that are undefined.

```js
export const removeUndefinedValues: (obj: Record<PropertyKey, any>) => Record<PropertyKey, any> = (obj: Record<PropertyKey, any>) => {
    if (obj) {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach((key: PropertyKey) => {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
                if (obj[key] === undefined) {
                    console.log(`Removing property ${key.toString()} with value ${obj[key]}`)
                    delete obj[key]
                }

            }
        })
    }
    return obj
}
```

I added this to the object prototype with

```js
Object.prototype.removeUndefinedValues = function () {
    return removeUndefinedValues(this)
}
```

This seems to work, but as soon as I use it in a large code base it breaks because some things in the package `browserslist` become undefined. I solved this by using the following code instead.

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'removeUndefinedValues', {
    value: function () {
        return removeUndefinedValues(this);
    },
    enumerable: false
});
```

However, I do not understand what is the difference. Why does the second code work and the first not?

Comment: It seems like by setting enumerable to true i get the behaviour of the first code.

Comment: The second method makes removeUndefinedValues non-enumerable which is probably what you want anyway because nowadays people don't always bother to check if object.hasOwnProperty(key) when iterating objects like in the old days when you could only add methods directly to the prototype.

Comment: @PHPGuru, I read on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty that enumerable is false by default. That would imply that enumerable: false is not necessary.

Comment: Yes indeed. But it only defaults to false if you use Object.defineProperty to add the method, not if you add it directly as you did with Object.prototype.removeUndefinedValues = function () {
    return removeUndefinedValues(this)
}